# Wcf - 3 retries before exception?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-4.0, request

I was asked to build a mechanism for 3 retries before generating a request exception.

We have this topology :

[image]

`Service1` calls `Service2`.

If 3 times in a row has failed - generate an excpetion.

Is there any retry mechanism in `WCF` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WCF technology addressing this is **Reliable Messaging**. I think **MaxRetryCount** is the attribute you are looking for.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968874/233095) is an example with a custom binding using MaxRetryCount.