# Retry call to service reference

Tags: c#, wcf

Is it possible to set up retries for a call to a service reference ? 
Say, if a call to the service reference times out, then the proxy will try again 3 times.

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195959/wcf-3-retries-before-exception

Comment: Or this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151361/wcf-retry-proxy