# WCF binding setting - maxRetryCount="Integer"

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am trying to set the binding setting  maxRetryCount="Integer" but it states "The maxRetryCount attribute is not allowed".

I see it being referenced/used in many examples.

What am I doing wrong?

Want to set this attribute(setting)to see if it stops an error I am getting: The maximum retry count has been exceeded with no response from the remote endpoint. The reliable session was faulted. This is often an indication that the remote endpoint is no longer available.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>  
   <appSettings>
     <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
   </appSettings>
   <system.web>
     <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
     <customErrors mode="Off"/>
   </system.web>  
   <system.serviceModel>    
     <services>
       <service name="dedicated_servers.dedicated_servers.DedicatedServerApi">
         <endpoint address="User" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="dedicated_servers.dedicated_servers.IDedicatedServerApiUser"      bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityConfig">
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="Server" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="dedicated_servers.dedicated_servers.IDedicatedServerApiServer"      bindingConfiguration="NoSecurityConfig">
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
       </service>
     </services>
     <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="NoSecurityConfig" openTimeout="00:05:00" closeTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:05:00">
           <security mode="None">
             <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
             <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
           </security>
           <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" maxRetryCount="8" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
     <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968874/12085).  To paraphrase, you can't set the `maxRetryCount` on `wsHttpBinding` but you can do some custom binding trickery to make it work.

Comment: Thanks...I tried that but still get message. It appears to be a volume issue. With low volume being passed back to the client, it works fine - even before adding the maxRetryCount and now also after adding the maxRetryCount. With large voume, that is when I get that message.